# How do I reset a PowerShell build step script to use the template?

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I have a build script template that does all the usual build script things: sets up a bunch of parameters, configures various config values, and runs a PowerShell script to run a build step.  This template is inherited by a handful of build steps that customize things for different code branches.

TeamCity allows values from the template to be overridden in the inherited build steps.  In the case of parameters, there's an option to cancel the override and reset it to the default from the template.  But I can't find the corresponding option for PowerShell scripts.  I have a script that's gotten badly out of sync with the template; where is the option to tell it to stop overriding the template's script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching around, it appears that there's no way to reset the PowerShell script *per se,* but it is possible to reset the entire build step that contains the script to use the template rather than an overridden version.  This option is found on the Build Steps list, in the dropdown next to the "Edit" link.